# How do I find the latest row of a datetime up to the minute only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following basic SQL statement.

```
SELECT 
    [Cycle_Id], [Machine], [Machine_Action], [Cycle_Date]
FROM 
    [EKAM].[dbo].[Machine_Cycle]
WHERE 
    Machine = 'OKK 2' 
    AND Cycle_Date BETWEEN '2016-08-15 7:59:00' AND '2016-08-18 7:59:00'
ORDER BY 
    Cycle_Date DESC
```

It returns the following data.

```
Cycle_Id   Machine   Machine_Action    Cycle_Date
--------------------------------------------------------------
85220      OKK 2     UP                2016-08-15 09:07:39.883
85221      OKK 2     DOWN              2016-08-15 09:08:04.367
85223      OKK 2     UP                2016-08-15 09:08:44.367
85226      OKK 2     DOWN              2016-08-15 09:08:55.367
85233      OKK 2     UP                2016-08-15 09:09:38.367
85234      OKK 2     DOWN              2016-08-15 09:10:07.367
```

However I need it to pull the following data instead.  The main difference being I only want the latest row per minute.

```
85220   OKK 2   UP      2016-08-15 09:07:39.883
85226   OKK 2   DOWN    2016-08-15 09:08:55.367
85233   OKK 2   UP      2016-08-15 09:09:38.367
85234   OKK 2   DOWN    2016-08-15 09:10:07.367
```

I have too much data and I'm not worried about data as fine as milliseconds and seconds. I only want one row per minute, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this for some reason.  Perhaps I just didn't get enough sleep last night.

I feel like I need to recast the Cycle_Date to get rid of seconds and milliseconds, but where do I go from there?

Comment: what is the criteria to shink down your result? how do you decide to skip 85221 for example?

Comment: @techspider "The main difference being I only want the latest row per minute."

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah, got the point!! You are quick to answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `BETWEEN` here as that will exclude almost all of the last minute which probably isn't what you want.

To just preserve the latest row per minute you can use

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT 
   Cycle_Id
  ,[Machine]
  ,[Machine_Action]
  ,[Cycle_Date]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(Minute, 0, CycleDate) 
                      ORDER BY CycleDate DESC, Cycle_Id DESC) AS RN
FROM [EKAM].[dbo].[Machine_Cycle]
WHERE Machine = 'OKK 2' AND 
Cycle_Date >= '2016-08-15 7:59:00' AND Cycle_Date < '2016-08-18 8:00:00'
)
SELECT 
   Cycle_Id
  ,[Machine]
  ,[Machine_Action]
  ,[Cycle_Date]
FROM T
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Cycle_Date DESC
```

Comment: I believe `ORDER BY Cycle_Id` at the end instead of `Cycle_Date`

Comment: @techspider yes could be better. This would only come into play if there two rows tied for the maximum with the exact same time down to the millisecond in `Cycle_Date`. I'll add it in as a tie breaker as otherwise it could return the wrong row if the two columns aren't increasing strictly in synch.

Comment: I would have never thought to do it this way.  Thanks for the help!